# How to create JWT token using IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

In my application (.Net core application) using IdentityServer4, at present creates "Reference" Token for authentication. But I would need to change the token type from "Reference" type to "JWT" token. I found couple of articles regarding that and tried as mentioned, but still I am not able to get the "JWT" token and I am getting "Reference" token only.

I followed the details mentioned in the below sites, but no luck.

*[IdentityServer4 requesting a JWT / Access Bearer Token using the password grant in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924029/identityserver4-requesting-a-jwt-access-bearer-token-using-the-password-grant)*

*https://codebrains.io/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-asp-net-core-api-with-identityserver-4-part-1/*

*https://andrewlock.net/a-look-behind-the-jwt-bearer-authentication-middleware-in-asp-net-core/*

Can anyone let me know how could we change the token type from "Reference" to "JWT" token? Is there any custom code/class to be created to achieve this?

Below is the code used in my Client class.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "Client1",
                ClientName = "Client1",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword, 
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityScope.OpenId,
                    IdentityScope.Profile,
                    ResourceScope.Customer,
                    ResourceScope.Info,
                    ResourceScope.Product,
                    ResourceScope.Security,
                    ResourceScope.Sales,
                    ResourceScope.Media,
                    ResourceScope.Nfc,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                // Use reference token so mobile user (resource owner) can revoke token when log out. 
                // Jwt token is self contained and cannot be revoked
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AccessTokenLifetime = CommonSettings.AccessTokenLifetime,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = CommonSettings.AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = CommonSettings.SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime,
                IncludeJwtId = true,
                Enabled = true
            },
```

And in my startup.cs, I have this below code.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CommonSettings.IDSRV_CONNECTION_STRING].ConnectionString;
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                // base-address of your identityserver
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:1839/"; 
                // name of the API resource
                options.Audience = "api1";

                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
            }
            );
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options => setupAction(options))
            .AddSigningCredential(loadCert())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Helpers.Clients.Get())          
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Resources.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Resources.GetApiResources()).AddDeveloperSigningCredential()          

            .AddConfigStoreCache().AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
            //Adds a key for validating tokens. They will be used by the internal token validator and will show up in the discovery document.
            .AddValidationKey(loadCert());

 builder.AddConfigStore(options =>
                {

                    //CurrentEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Testing") ?
                    // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = dbBuilder => { dbBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr); };
                })
            .AddOperationalDataStore(options =>
            {
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                options.ConfigureDbContext = dbBuilder => { dbBuilder.UseSqlServer(connStr); };
                // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                options.TokenCleanupInterval = CommonSettings.TokenCleanupInterval;
            });
}
```

Kindly let me know, what change(s) to be done to get JWT token. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You used both in-memory clients and database store. Because you added database store after in-memory, you should change db record.

Comment: Earlier I used DBstore only.. When I tried, i added those in-memory statements. But earlier when i used DB also it was not working. So with DB store, JWT token would not work?

Comment: The statement `AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt` should do the trick. Are you sure you are reading the configuration from the shown ciient?

Comment: @Ruard - yes I am using the same client when i m calling the 'connect/token'